# Expected Rotation Curves

Tags: astrophysics, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

As you know, it is expected that the velocity of stars and gas should slow down the further they are from a galaxy's center. However, in many cases, it does not slow down as expected, and this discrepancy is often attributed to the presence of dark matter.

How can I obtain the expected radius - velocity plot for certain galaxies? What informations or data should I have about those galaxies to plot it? Can you provide me some links about it?

I need to plot the observed rotation cuves and expected ones like in the image that Ihave added to this post

[image].

Comment: you are quoting a figure from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_rotation_curve . Have yoy looked at the articles referenced for this curve? the first  https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/311/2/441/965167?login=true shows the complexity of the analysis to get at curves like this . It cannot be  answered within a format of questions an answers. A lot of details of the specific galaxy are needed.